# Understanding Momentum conservation at a Control Volume

Tags: fluid-mechanics, partial-differential-equations

I am taking a course in Fluid Dynamics, and we discussed the conservation of momentum in class:

$$\dot{M}_{out,x} = \rho u (dydz) u|_{x+dx} + \rho v (dxdz) u|_{x+dx} + \rho v (dxdy) u|_{x+dx}$$
I understand this notation as follows:
$$\dot{M}_{out,x} = \rho u(x+dx) (dydz) u(x+dx) + \rho v(y) (dxdz) u(x+dx) + \rho w(z) (dxdy) u(x+dx)$$

The next line in the equation on the notes reads:
$$\dot{M}_{out,x} = \rho u (dydz) u + \frac{\partial (\rho u (dydz)u)}{\partial x}dx + \rho v (dydz) u + \frac{\partial (\rho v (dydz)u)}{\partial y}dy + \rho u (dydz) u + \frac{\partial (\rho w (dydz)u)}{\partial z}dz $$
I can see they did a taylor expansion, but since the equation reads $|_{x+dx}$ at every component, I do not understand why the taylor expansion was carried for $|_{y+dy}$ and $|_{z+dz}$. I am really struggling to arrive to that last form.